# mysql injection error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to inject sql union statement in this statement.

```
select id, email, `password` from users
where id = 1 union select 1,2,3;
order by users.id
```

But it returns an error:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order by users.id' at line 1

how can I get this statement to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

remove the `;` before the `ORDER BY` clause

```
select id, email, password 
from users where id = 1 
union 
select 1,2,3
order by id
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  id, email, password
FROM
    (
        SELECT  id, email, password, 1 AS orders
        FROM    users 
        WHERE   id = 1 
        UNION 
        SELECT  1,2,3,2
    ) s
ORDER BY orders, id
```

Comment: I can remove ; but can't remove users.id or replace it by id because it's original code, now when remove ; the error is: [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'users.id' in 'order clause'

Comment: the original statement is [select id, email, password 
from users where id = ?
order by users.id]
and I can only access the parameter, so I can't inject your code.

Comment: `SELECT  id, email, password
FROM
    (
        SELECT  id, email, password, 1 AS orders
        FROM    users 
        WHERE   id = ?
        UNION 
        SELECT  1,2,3,2
    ) s
ORDER BY orders, id` how about this?

Comment: it's nice but I can't inject it, where I can make modification is here:
select id, email, `password` from users
where id = [inject code]
order by users.id
and not any other place in statement.

Comment: to be honest, i don't get the term `inject` `:(`

Comment: no problem, I've been trying for two days now with no success.